# Quais métodos HTTP usam payload?

Tags: http

Estou fazendo um monitoramento para os serviços da minha empresa e preciso dessa informação para prosseguir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os métodos HTTP padrão são:

```
Método  | Payload no Request | Payload no Response
--------+--------------------+---------------------
HEAD    | Não                | Não
GET     | Não                | Sim
POST    | Sim                | Sim
PUT     | Sim                | Sim
DELETE  | Não                | Sim
OPTIONS | Às vezes           | Sim
TRACE   | Não                | Sim
CONNECT | Sim                | Sim
PATCH   | Sim                | Sim
```

Fonte: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Summary_table

Comment: Ótimo! Agradeço.